# How to install spyder3 on ubuntu 16.04 docker container

Tags: docker, spyder

I am trying to build an docker image based on Ubuntu 16.04. Is it possible to install and use spyder3 on this image?

What I have done so far...

1. Added a normal user on Ubuntu 16.04(base image)
2. Installed python3.6.4
3. Installed spyder3

and I get this error:

```sh
genie@667b3f2734a1:~$ spyder3

Spyder: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder is a desktop application, so it needs an X server running on Linux for it to work. So you need to add `python3-pyqt5` to your docker image, which should bring Xorg and all its dependencies with it. Then you need to start the server with `startx`.